# How do I force Wubi to install a 32-bit version?

Tags: installation, wubi, 32-bit

I'm using Windows 8 (32bit) customer preview and installing WUBI Ubuntu 12,04.1.
I down loaded 32 bit installer from ubuntu dot com, The wubi installer says AMD 64 xt.
I had a previous 12,04 install and in the terminal typed in `uname -a`, it say's 64 bit. 
I also opened detail from the system and it read 64 bit system.

My question is: how to ensure that a windows/wubi/ubuntu/installer is 32 bit or 64 bit BEFORE making a commitment to install from the wrong wubi install?

After posting this I did another wubi installation. Signed into ubuntu, opened system settings, open Details: OS Type 64 Bit. Why is it doing this? I have a 32 Bit machine: Toshiba Satellite A-215 S5818 (previous Windows Vista)<--wiped clean. from an earlier installation of Ubuntu 10.10 which worked, in feb 2012 i installed Win8 Customer Preview Release (32Bit) which took over the BOOT order and 140 GB Hard Disk. I am trying patiently to install WUBI 32 BIT Ubuntu 12.04 Install, it keeps returning 64 BIT install.. Why??

I should also mention that i was successful in a dual boot install ubuntu 10.04/win8 32 bit install and upgraded to 12.04 which is fine for now, but i want a win8/wubi/ubuntu12.04 32 bit working not 64 bit breaking what i have. 
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, WUBI knows it better than you do. Toshiba Satellite A-215 S581 comes with the  AMD Turion64 CPU, definitely a 64b processor.

You wouldn't be able to run the 64b OS on a 32b machine, but you are -- since you could run `uname -a`.

If you really want a choice, for whatever reason, then drop WUBI, install Ubuntu on a dedicated partition and use CD / USB stick image which you can choose to be 32b rather than 64b. In any case, what is wrong about having the 64b system?

Answer (score 1):

> From the [official WUBI guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Can_I_force_Wubi_to_download_and_install_a_32_bit_version_of_Ubuntu.3F)

**Can I force Wubi to download and install a 32 bit version of Ubuntu?**

Yes. Either pre-download the appropriate 32 bit ISO manually and place it in the same folder as Wubi.exe or start Wubi from the command prompt with the "--32bit" argument.

To modify arguments without using the command prompt, right-click Wubi.exe and select "Create Shortcut". Then right-click the shortcut, select Properties, and modify the Target line, for example: `"C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Desktop\wubi.exe" --32bit`

Comment: Thank you I will give this a go at it. It's late and I am tired, lil frustrated, and confused. Thank you for your time and efforts.
Namaste to All.